# Reorganise table of contents by section not chapter

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, indexing, labbook

I have my document in chronological order with a chapter a day. But the contents should be ordered by section, chapter, then subsection (i.e. Experiment-Date-Method). I cannot find a way of doing this is there some command im missing?

I'm not sure if I should be using a table of contents at all maybe an index would work better?

I'm using `\documentclass{labbook}` (https://ctan.org/pkg/labbook?lang=en). Not sure if this makes a difference or not though.

Desired output:

[image: Image of Desired Output]

```
\documentclass[oneside]{labbook}

% \labday{}
% \experiment{}
% \subexperiment{}

% Template: \newexperiment{<abbrev>}[<short form>]{<long form>}

\newexperiment{E1}{Experiment 1}
\newexperiment{E2}{Experiment 2}

\newsubexperiment{M1}{Method 1}
\newsubexperiment{M2}{Method 2}
% \newsubexperiment{M3}{Method 3}
% \newsubexperiment{M4}{Method 4}



\begin{document}

\printindex
\tableofcontents

\labday{07/08/23}
\experiment{E1}
\subexperiment{M1}

\begingroup % Irrelevant formatting
\let\clearpage\relax % Irrelevant formatting

\labday{08/08/23}
\experiment{E2}
\subexperiment{M1}

\labday{09/08/23}
\experiment{E1}
\subexperiment{M1}
\subexperiment{M2}

\newpage % Irrelevant formatting

\labday{10/08/23}
\experiment{E2}
\subexperiment{M1}
\subexperiment{M2}

\endgroup % Irrelevant formatting

\end{document}
```